# In R, how to sum the distance between rows (each one is a GPS coordinate)?

Tags: r, gps

I have many GPS points and what I want is the sum of distances between two subsequent points (rows) in a given date so I can have a daily track distance.

Each day has about 200 GPS points. Subsequent points means two rows in which the first is earlier than the second. Because I need the total distance among these points, it must take into consideration the row order of the column "time" within a given day (column "date").

Thank you!

My table sorta looks like this:

```
date        time       lat        lon    
18-Jan-18 12:48:39 -24.061464 -47.99523
18-Jan-18 12:48:48 -24.06163  -47.995354
18-Jan-18 12:53:17 -24.06175  -47.995277
```

Comment: Just to clarify, what would be your expected output for those 3 rows?

Comment: Hi Edward. The expected output would be a few meters between each row (the GPS points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pointDistance` from the package `raster` to calculate the distance. `lag` from `dplyr` will help calculating on subsequent points. `replace_na` from `tidyr` is very convenient, but you could use your favorite way of dealing with `NA`.

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(Distance = pointDistance(cbind(lon,lat),cbind(lag(lon),lag(lat)),lonlat = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(TotalDistance = cumsum(replace_na(Distance,0)))
#       date     time       lat       lon Distance TotalDistance
#1 18-Jan-18 12:48:39 -24.06146 -47.99523       NA       0.00000
#2 18-Jan-18 12:48:48 -24.06163 -47.99535 22.29547      22.29547
#3 18-Jan-18 12:53:17 -24.06175 -47.99528 15.42660      37.72207
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "18-Jan-18", class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(1:3, .Label = c("12:48:39", "12:48:48", 
    "12:53:17"), class = "factor"), lat = c(-24.061464, -24.06163, 
    -24.06175), lon = c(-47.99523, -47.995354, -47.995277)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems very promising! It worked wonders!!!!! I am so grateful!

Comment: However, I was wondering how can I add a loop to your script (because I have many different dates on my table)?

Comment: You could add a `group_by` line, such as `group_by(date) %>%` immediately before the first `mutate` line.  It will be easier to help if you provide better example data and expected output.

Comment: That addition completely solved my problem. My table is mostly like the sample I copied, but with different dates (and, obviously, different lat and longs too). Grouping per date is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much